# How to slice an array by key, not offset?

Tags: php, arrays, slice, offset, array-filter

PHP function **array_slice()** returns sequence of elements by offset like this:

```
// sample data
$a = array('a','b','c',100=>'aa',101=>'bb',102=>'cc'); 

// outputs empty array because offset 100 not defined
print_r(array_slice($a,100));
```

Current function arguments:

```
array_slice ( $array, $offset, $length, $preserve_keys)
```

I need something like this:

```
array_slice ( $array, **$key**, $length, $preserve_keys)
```

That outputs this according to above print_r:

```
array (
   100 => aa,
   101 => bb,
   102 => cc
)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To find the offset of the key, use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search) to search through the keys, which can be retrieved with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys).  `array_search()` will return `FALSE` when the specified key (`100`) is not present in the array (`$a`).

```
$key = array_search(100, array_keys($a), true);
if ($key !== false) {
    $slice = array_slice($a, $key, null, true);
    var_export($slice);
}
```

Prints:

```
array (
  100 => 'aa',
  101 => 'bb',
  102 => 'cc',
)
```

Answer (score 9):

Returns parts of `$array` whose keys exist in the array `$keys`:

```
array_intersect_key($array,array_flip($keys));
```

Comment: Not sure if your answer answers the OP's question, but this is exactly what I've been googling for :)

Comment: @brett
me too :)

Answer (score 3):

### Alternative solution

If you want to **slice the array by using keys for the items you want to get**, you could use the following custom function to do so:

```
function array_slice_keys($array, $keys = null) {
    if ( empty($keys) ) {
        $keys = array_keys($array);
    }
    if ( !is_array($keys) ) {
        $keys = array($keys);
    }
    if ( !is_array($array) ) {
        return array();
    } else {
        return array_intersect_key($array, array_fill_keys($keys, '1'));
    }
}
```

***Usage:***

```
$ar = [
    'key1' => 'a',
    'key2' => 'b',
    'key3' => 'c',
    'key4' => 'd',
    'key5' => 'e',
    'key6' => 'f',
];

// Get the values from the array with these keys:
$items = array_slice_keys( $ar, array('key2', 'key3', 'key5') );
```

***Result:***

```
Array
(
    [key2] => b
    [key3] => c
    [key5] => e
)
```

Comment: Why is `$keys` an optional argument? It seems odd that this function handles so many defensive cases of getting no keys, getting an array without keys, getting... an empty array?

Comment: +1 I prefer this over `array_search` answer because it's easier to add more keys this way. But you could've just answered `array_intersect_key($array, array_fill_keys($keys, '1'))` without the (unnecessary) function.